# How to version assets/images on the entire CMS?

Tags: joomla-3.x, images, cache, versions

Is there any way to force versioning of specific assets or media types (like `.webp` images) on all pages of the CMS? I'd imagine it'd be an extension or something that adds `?ver=xyz` type of postfix to HTML and CSS right before it's output, where `xyz` is set in the admin panel. I can't find anything related to this problem though.

This is to refresh browser cache on demand without the necessity of renaming files.

Answer (score 3):

In Joomla 3 for js and css assets you can add `'version'=>'auto'` to the attributes of `addStyleSheet` and `addScript`:

```
$document->addStyleSheet("...demo.css", array('version'=>'auto'));
```

as described in https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_JavaScript_and_CSS_to_the_page#$options_and_$attributes_Parameters

In Joomla 4 the web asset manager does this by default.

I'm not aware of any core joomla functionality which adds versioning to images and other types of media, but you may be able to find a joomla extension which supports this.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking primarily for images and and automatic way to do it so that it covers also random extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a small plugin, or use a plugin that can replace HTML code on the fly.

Let it search and replace all instances of `.webp"` in the HTML source with `.webp?your-own-version-number"`.

Answer (score 0):

[Responsive images](https://responsive-images.dgrammatiko.dev/) will do that.